# Is the Lance Shield as strong or stronger than the Gunlance Shield?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I'm thinking of starting to use the Lance or Gunlance, and wasn't sure about this.

So basically:

- Do they block the same?
- Does one block certain attack the other can't?
- When blocking, do you take more damage with one than the other?

I'm just concerned about the weapons themselves mostly.  If armor skills change one more drastically than the other, please include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, the Lance and Gunlance shields function exactly the same way; they'll block the same attacks, take the same amount of chip damage, and block animation. Armor skills treat them the same way, too; Guard and Guard Up will do the same things, etc.

The only difference is that the Lance has more defensive moves available; the Power Guard most notably.

In terms of defensive strength, they're exactly the same. When you add in the weapon, though, Lance gives a bit more defensive versatility.

[Source](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Lance)

Comment: In regards to them blocking attacks, is that just when you holding the button to put your shield up, or does it block your flank as well when you are walking with it out, not actively blocking (or if it sheaths and is put on your back, can't remember if you always have to hold the shield or if you put it on your back when not out, does that block you from behind as well)?

Comment: Only when you're actively blocking, or performing an attack with a blocking component, which I believe the Lance Dash has.

Comment: Not sure if Lance/Gunlance has something similar, but if you empower a charge blades shield, then it sometimes automatically goes into blocking mode to block an attack (not sure which circumstances)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Those are known as "Guard Points", and don't require charged shield, just good timing. (But if your shield IS charged, they can deal damage and/or stun the monster!)

Answer (score 0):

Lance and Gunlance share the same default guard values. However, while Gunlance only has a standard guard, Lance can:

- Counter Thrust, a reactive attack in which you enter a guarding stance and thrust powerfully when you are hit from the front,
- Empower Guard, which reduces the knockback but increases the damage
- Guard Dash, a step but guards instead of dodges,
- (*Iceborne-exclusive*) enter the Guard Shot Stance, in which you cannot move but **your defensive ability is improved than in the standard guard**.

Therefore, despite having the same basic defensive capabilities, Lance falls into a more technical and defensive weapon, while Gunlance falls into a more simple and aggressive weapon. Iceborne even enlarges the gap further by adding the aforementioned Guard Shot stance in which you can turtle more effectively.